# Como pegar o valor de um input com getParameter?

Tags: java, html

Não estou conseguindo pegar o valor do seguinte input.

```
<input type="text" name="rua" class="form-control" id="rua" 
                                        placeholder="Rua/Av/Estrada" disabled required>
```

Esse campo ele é preenchido através de um webservice. Que é um serviço dos correios "VIACep".

Só que durante o cadastro desse input, não estou conseguindo pegar o valor que o serviço coloca nele.

Estou utilizando o getParameter.

```
String pEndereco = request.getParameter("rua");
```

O código passa nessa linha e retorna null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inputs que contem o atributo `disabled` não são enviados junto com os dados do formulário.

Remova o atributo `disabled` e deixe apenas `readonly` (somente leitura) que vai funcionar.

Vale lembrar que nem sempre o `webservice` vai ter todos os valores ou algum pode estar desatualizado, então acho que você devia permitir a alteração do campo.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Diego Schmidt, funcionou.

Essa questão do webservice não funcionar sempre, eu vou validar com meu cliente, se for a vontade dele eu deixo liberado.

Comment: @KennedyAnderson Pode ser um endereço novo que ainda não está na base dos correios ou desatualizado, no site do webservice diz que pode ter algum desatualizado. abss